# sonarqube upgrade 4.5.4 to 5.1 fails

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I'm trying to upgrade from 4.5.4 to 5.1 but it fails.
Does it come from an incompatible plugin or something else ?

My list of plugins :

- sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
- sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar
- sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.7.jar
- sonar-css-plugin-1.1.jar
- sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar
- sonar-timeline-plugin-1.4.jar
- sonar-groovy-plugin-1.1.jar
- sonar-useless-code-tracker-plugin-1.0.jar
- sonar-issue-assign-plugin-1.5.jar
- sonar-views-plugin-2.8.jar
- sonar-issues-density-plugin-1.0.jar
- sonar-web-plugin-2.3.jar
- sonar-java-plugin-3.1.jar
- sonar-xml-plugin-1.2.jar
- sonar-javascript-plugin-2.5.jar

Here's the log. I started from a clean data/es empty directory

```
    --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.04.28 13:23:17 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process7364011964623837555properties
2015.04.28 13:23:18 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.04.28 13:23:18 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9003
...
2015.04.28 13:23:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2015.04.28 13:23:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy app: motionchart
2015.04.28 13:23:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy app: views
2015.04.28 13:23:32 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b14 [linux-amd64]
2015.04.28 13:23:32 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.04.28 13:23:45 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2015.04.28 13:23:45 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9001"]
2015.04.28 13:23:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.04.28 13:23:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9001
2015.04.28 13:23:46 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
...
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddUuidToAnalysisReports: migrating =======================================
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("analysis_reports")
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0120s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_column("analysis_reports", "uuid", :string, {:limit=>50, :null=>false})
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0030s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("analysis_reports")
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0090s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- remove_column("analysis_reports", "report_data")
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.1030s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("analysis_reports")
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0110s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- remove_column("analysis_reports", "snapshot_id")
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.1140s
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddUuidToAnalysisReports: migrated (0.2560s) ==============================
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2015.04.28 13:31:14 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2015.04.28 13:31:17 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: arkoon:9090)
2015.04.28 13:31:17 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index sourcelines
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [sourcelines] creating index, cause [api], shards [1]/[0], mappings []
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type sourcelines/sourceline
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [sourcelines] create_mapping [sourceline]
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index activities
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [activities] creating index, cause [api], shards [1]/[0], mappings []
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type activities/activity
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [activities] create_mapping [activity]
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index issues
2015.04.28 13:31:18 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [issues] creating index, cause [api], shards [1]/[0], mappings []
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type issues/authorization
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [issues] create_mapping [authorization]
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type issues/issue
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [issues] create_mapping [issue]
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index users
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [users] creating index, cause [api], shards [1]/[0], mappings []
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type users/user
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [users] create_mapping [user]
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index views
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [views] creating index, cause [api], shards [1]/[0], mappings []
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type views/view
2015.04.28 13:31:19 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1430220197325] [views] create_mapping [view]
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=ou=users,o=internet, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0})), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Group mapping: LdapGroupMapping{baseDn=ou=Sonar,ou=Developpement,ou=appli,o=internet, idAttribute=cn, requiredUserAttributes=[dn], request=(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))}
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://charlemagne.lan:389: OK
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[views] views plugin licensed to FOO, PRODUCTION [Expiration: 2015-11-26, Server: 11151325d743386]
2015.04.28 13:31:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
2015.04.28 13:31:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
2015.04.28 13:31:44 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
Could not execute normalization for stack
    org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:136)
    org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:82)
    org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:62)
    org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:370)
    org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:356)
    org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:104)
    org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:74)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:850)
    org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Log with the debug information added

```
2015.06.12 11:34:38 ERROR web[o.s.s.s.IndexQueue] Could not execute normalization for stack
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository must be set
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:118) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:82) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:62) [sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:370) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:356) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:104) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:74) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:850) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81) [sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository must be set
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.rule.RuleKey.of(RuleKey.java:46) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.qualityprofile.db.ActiveRuleDto.getKey(ActiveRuleDto.java:65) ~[sonar-core-5.1.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.index.ActiveRuleNormalizer.normalize(ActiveRuleNormalizer.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.index.ActiveRuleNormalizer.normalize(ActiveRuleNormalizer.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.action.InsertDto.doCall(InsertDto.java:47) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.action.IndexAction.call(IndexAction.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.action.IndexAction.call(IndexAction.java:28) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
... 1 common frames omitted
2015.06.12 11:34:38 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
Could not execute normalization for stack
org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:137)
org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:82)
org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:62)
org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:370)
org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:356)
org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:104)
org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:74)
org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:850)
org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43)
org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847)
org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126)
org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122)
org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is it only what you have in the logs? It looks like some information is missing at the end. You can also try to delete the <sonar_install>/data/es folder and restart SonarQube to see if this is reproducible.

Comment: Just tried with an empty data/es directory. Nothing has changed. There is nothing at the end of the log I missed.

Comment: Something is strange with your log. Can you revert your DB, add "sonar.log.level=DEBUG" in your "conf/sonar.properties" file, restart the migration process and copy-paste the full log on http://pastebin.com please?

Comment: Added the debug properties, then launched upgrade process Whole log available at http://pastebin.com/AkTBQJpX

Comment: Not yet, your issue is really unexpected because some part of the error is missing. We'll be getting back to you.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you upgrade the Java plugin to the latest version (3.2) => http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin

Comment: I've just tested with java plugin 3.3, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam I just tested with the new version of sonarqube 511, I still get the same error. Is there something I can do to help diagnosing ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a bug that makes the exception silent. I pushed a fix in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/branch-5.1. Is it possible for you to build SonarQube from these sources ? Command-line is "mvn clean package". Zip is available in sonar-application/target. Thanks

Comment: @SimonBrandhof I finally got something new. I didn't manage to build all the artifacts, so I decided to only package the sonar-server artifact. I updated the original description.

Comment: @Dominique could you please execute the following SQL request ?

select a.id,
    a.profile_id as "profileId",
    a.rule_id as "ruleId",
    a.failure_level as "severity",
    a.inheritance as "inheritance",
    r.plugin_rule_key as "rulefield",
    r.plugin_name as "repository",
    qp.kee as "profileKey",
    a.created_at as "createdAt",
    a.updated_at as "updatedAt"
    from active_rules a
    LEFT JOIN rules_profiles qp ON qp.id=a.profile_id
    LEFT JOIN rules r ON r.id = a.rule_id

Comment: @SimonBrandhof here is the sql result : http://pastebin.com/dJDk1u34.
I have 8 rows with a null value for repository column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem comes from invalid XML rules (NULL repository in the table RULES on a few XML rules). Deleting them will fix the error. Before that could you please send me the result of SELECT * FROM RULES WHERE plugin_name IS NULL ? I will create a JIRA ticket accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I guess your assumption is wrong. The problem doesn't come from the fact there are rules with a NULL plugin_name, but it comes from the fact that there are no matching rows in rules for the active_rules or the rules_profile. SELECT * FROM RULES WHERE plugin_name IS NULL shows empty rows.

Comment: Looks like it's considered as a problem here http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5503?focusedCommentId=57485&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-57485